# What is returned by Server.GetLastError in Classic ASP?

Tags: debugging, asp-classic, getlasterror

I would like to know what kind of object is returned in Classic ASP by the function Server.GetLastError.

If this were a .net or JavaScript function, I would simply attach a debugger and see what is returned, but I don't have any tools to do that with Classic ASP code in the environment I work in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524846%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The GetLastError method returns an [ASPError Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524942%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) describing the
>   error condition that occurred. This method is available only before
>   the .asp file has sent any content to the client.

Answer (score 2):

`Server.GetLastError` returns the last [`ASPError` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524942%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), representing the last ASP error that has occured on the server. You can see the definition of the object in the MSDN link.

In general, you can still lookup ASP and VBScript objects and syntax on MSDN.